# Round of column before GAWK summation

Tags: shell, awk

I want to round off the 29th column to 5 decimals before taking sum using GAWK. Code so far -

```
gawk -v OFMT=%.20g -F'\t' '{ sum += $29 } END{ print sum, NR-1}' table.csv
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Usually, you make the operations with the max precision, and round **after** all the ops are done - in your case round the **sum**.

Comment: Define how to "round" for your purposes - up, down, towards zero, away from zero, unbiased, or something else (see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding). [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input that demonstrates the type of rounding you need so we can help you. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: GNU AWK documentation has description of [Rounding Numbers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Round-Function.html) with function which does traditional rounding, independently of what `printf` do

Answer (score 1):

> before taking sum using GAWK

I think the following should work:

```
sum += sprintf("%.5f", $29)
```

But be wary of floating point precision.

Comment: all depends what type of rounding the OP wants and what type of rounding the awk on the OPs machine implements. On many machines it'll round a trailing ".5" towards the nearest even number (i.e. neither up nor down, but "unbiased") so 1.5 rounds to 2 but 2.5 also rounds to 2 which can be unintuitive.

Comment: 5 decimals generally excludes the exponent. So "%.5e" might be better.